# Ajax Success event does not fire when calling service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using JQuery to make a AJAX to a local service.  My local service is a HttpHandler (e.g., Request.ashx).  Within Request.ashx, it's responsiblity is to make a call to an external website (e.g., CallExternalWebsite()).  CallExternalWebsite() uses .NET's System.Net.WebRequest() to initiate a request.  When the external website is accessed, neither the success or error events are fired.  (*NOTE:  I have also tried this a WCF service hosted in IIS.  I am seeing the same results*)

Here are two scenarios:

This scenario works:

1. In ProcessRequest(), *comment out* callExternalWebsite().
2. For object o, intialize with data to simulate results.
3. Click on myButton
4. The success event fires on the client.
5. In Fiddler, I can see the header info.  I see Json result, etc.

This scenario does not work:

1. In ProcessRequest(), *enable* the call for callExternalWebsite().
2. For object o, callExternalWebsite() will return an appropriate object.
3. Click on myButton
4. The success event *does not* fires on the client.
5. In Fiddler, I can see the header info.  I see Json result, etc.
6. I know the callExternalWebsite() is working because I have it sending results to my phone.

To sum it up, the external http call within the HttpHandler is effecting the Ajax success event.

Here is a snippet from AJAX call:
(I was trying different interations)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myButton").click(function (event) {

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/Service/Request.ashx",
                data: '{"id" : "053252f3"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 20000,
                success: function (msg) {
                    AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: AjaxFailed
            });
        });
    });
```

In the HttpHandler Request.ashx,

```
public Void ProcessRequest(httpContent context)
{
//  Do some stuff....

// Make call to external web site
object o = callExternalWebsite (Uri, Data, "POST");

// Return results from callOtherWebsite 
        JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(o);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(json);

}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Steve

Comment: Are you sure the response is HTTP 200/OK?  I believe only status codes of 2xx are considdered a "Success"

Comment: Please can you post the code to `AjaxSucceeded`? Maybe there's a problem there. Try changing the success call to `alert("hello!")` or similar to confirm the success branch is not executing.

Comment: I changed success to:

`success: function(msg) { alert("hello"); }`

but still did not execute.

Here is the response back from the Request.ashx call:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2012 16:28:40 GMT
Content-Length: 84`

Everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this, msg vs msg.d:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myButton").click(function (event) {

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/Service/Request.ashx",
            data: '{"id" : "053252f3"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 20000,
            success: function (msg) {
                AjaxSucceeded(msg.d);
            },
            error: AjaxFailed
        });
    });
});
```